# Which are the statistical methodologies to consider when examining study group death rates but without considering time to death?

Tags: r, survival, binomial-distribution, simulation, monte-carlo

I have a dataset for a group of 66,000 subjects diagnosed with a dangerous condition, and the time it takes for death to occur (the “event”) or to not occur (survival or “censored”). I am pursuing survival analysis using R. However, what if I am not interested in time-to-event, but just want to study the end of period death/survival rate with the objective of deriving a probability distribution of death at year 5 for groups of subjects facing the same diagnosis? I’d like to explore other statistical options where time to event is not a consideration. Is this a matter of choosing a distribution (such as binomial since in this case the subjects either live or die) and running simulations using my group’s parameters?

In the case of my study group:

- Death rate (over 5 years) is 70.5%
- SDEV (population or sample) is 0.4562 based on calculating SDEV on patient status at study period end where 1 = death and 0 = alive or “censored”
- SERR is 0.0018

Comment: Do you have complete follow-up on all 66,000 subjects? Or was follow-up incomplete on some of them during the time period in question?

Comment: I have complete follow-up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With complete follow-up until death or 5 years after `time=0` you can do a simple binomial lived/died model if you prefer. That throws away a lot of potentially interesting information on the times to the events. You should consider extracting 5-year survival estimates from a full survival model, which provides the best of both types of survival estimate.

In either a binomial or a full survival model you have to be careful in defining the `time=0` reference, as it affects the interpretation of the results.

If your `time=0` reference for each individual is the date of diagnosis and you have complete data on all individuals until death or through 5 years after an individual's `time=0` (whichever came first), then you are modeling survival *from diagnosis*. That's often of the most interest.

If your `time=0` reference is some study-start calendar date shared among a set of individuals who already have the diagnosis, you would be modeling the survival of a cohort *from study start*. That might be hard to evaluate at the individual level or to generalize to other cohorts. That might make sense in some applications, but think carefully about which measure of survival makes the most sense for you.

You don't have to do any simulations with the data you present; the observed proportion speaks for itself if you don't want to do any modeling of covariates. Your 0.705 probability of death at 5 years means a variance of $0.705*(1-0.705)=0.207975$. The square root of that gives the standard deviation of $0.456$, and the standard error is the standard deviation divided by the square root of your 66,000 cases, for a standard error of 0.0018.